# How to Print a React Component into PDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, printing, react-pdf

I have a data entry app created with React with a node express server backed by an SQL database. At the end of data entry the application creates the finalised form(currently coded as a component with HTML & CSS)with the values from the state.

On the final review page where the user confirms the data is correct and hit submit, I want to give the user the option to save the form as a PDF (also possibly email the created PDF as an attachment to an email)

Code on the review page looks as below

```
import AccCompetency from './forms/51_AccCompetency';




export class FormReview extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value:0};
  }


  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //some more methods here

  }

  back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  }
  repeat = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.startAgain();
  }




  render() {
    const {values} = this.props;
    const formId=values.formId;



    switch (formId)  {
      case "51":
        return (


          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <React.Fragment>

              <AppBar title="Review Record"/>
                <GridList style={{height: 450,maxWidth:'90%', borderStyle:'solid',borderColor:'grey',borderWidth:1, marginRight:'10%', marginLeft:'10%', marginTop:35}}>
                <EffectsOfControls nextStep={this.nextStep} handleChange={this.handleChange} values={values}/></GridList>
                <Grid item xs={10} style={{marginLeft:'10%',marginRight:'10%',marginTop:20}}>
                <RaisedButton label="Email & Save" secondary={true} onClick={this.continue} fullWidth='true' style={{marginTop:20, height:60}}/>
                <ButtonGroup variant="contained"  style={{marginTop:20}} fullWidth >
                <Button onClick={this.continue}>Save Only</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.back}>Back</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
                </Grid>
            </React.Fragment>
          </MuiThemeProvider>

        )

  default:
        return (


          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <React.Fragment>

              <AppBar title="Error occured"/>
                <GridList style={{height: 450,maxWidth:'90%', borderStyle:'solid',borderColor:'grey',borderWidth:1, marginRight:'10%', marginLeft:'10%', marginTop:35}}>
                <h1>Program has encountered an error (The page requested may still be under development). <br></br> Please go back or start again! </h1></GridList>
                <Grid item xs={10} style={{marginLeft:'10%',marginRight:'10%',marginTop:20}}>
                <ButtonGroup variant="contained"  style={{marginTop:20}} fullWidth >
                <Button onClick={this.back}>Go back</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.repeat}>Go back home</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
                </Grid>
            </React.Fragment>
          </MuiThemeProvider>

        )
        }
```

the component shown in the switch statement can vary in length depending on user's selection can sometimes exceed 2,3 pages in length.

ideally I would like a `save=e=>{}` function which prints the component into a PDF so i can then use that file as an attachment for an email. What's the best way of coding this?

Comment: is this what you looking for? https://github.com/ivmarcos/react-to-pdf

Comment: It says it only support single page printing, my component usually extend over a couple of pages when i actually hit ctrl+p during viewing

Comment: Any ideas @Gnujoow?